# Can the identity matrix be a product of 2 non-square matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For example if AB produces $I_m$ where $I_m$ is the mxm identity matrix, I know A must have m rows and B must have m columns but do both have to be mxm?

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$AB$ always has the same number of rows as $A$ and the same number of columns as $B$, and for the multiplication to be possible the number of columns of $A$ is the number of rows of $B$.  So in this case you want $A$ to be $m \times n$ and $B$ should be $n \times m$.

Yes, it is possible as long as $n \ge m$.

For some easy examples, suppose the last $n-m$ columns of $A$ are $0$...